# Navigator from MaterialApp builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to embed my whole App into an AppBar and a Footer.
So I tried giving a custom Builder to my MaterialApp which look like this (I replaced the footer and the app bar by a button for clarity)

```
import 'package:epicture/scenes/Landing.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      initialRoute: '/',
      builder: (context, child) => Container(
          child: FlatButton(
                child: Text('Click me'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/app'),
      )),
      // In my current code
      builder: (context, child) => Embedder(child),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/': (context) => Landing(),
        '/app': (context) => Text('My App !'),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But on press of the 'Click me' button, an error is raised saying that the context doesn't have a Navigator

`the context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget`

But actually, the button is a footer that can be clicked to change page from every page.

I would like to know how to have access to the navigator from the custom builder and if I simply head toward the wrong way for having the same pattern in every page of my application (Footer + header)

Answer (score 23):

You cannot access `Navigator` with `context` from inside the `builder` as any widget returned by this `builder` will be parent for the navigator.

So, what do I do? Can I access navigator here, how?

Yeah! You can, create a `GlobalKey` and pass it to your `MaterialApp`. Then use that key to access `Navigator` inside your `builder`.

Example:

```
import 'package:epicture/scenes/Landing.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigator = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      initialRoute: '/',
      navigatorKey: _navigator,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Container(
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Text('Click me'),
            onPressed: () => _navigator.currentState.pushNamed('/app'),
          ),
        );
      },
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/': (context) => Landing(),
        '/app': (context) => Text('My App !'),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: And what if the Button is actually a class of mine, let's call it `Embedder`, do I have to pass the navigator in its constructor ? (See edit)

Comment: Yeah, you can pass in constructor. Makes sense to do it if your `Embedder` is the only class using it. Any child of the embedder having access to navigator might also need key to access it. Having small number of children, you can pass in constructor. If that's not the case, you can make your `Embedder` a `InheritedWidget` so all it's children can access navigator. Or use any other method too.

Comment: Is there any way I can access the current route then in the Widget `Embedder` ?

Comment: Any idea how to provide that key thru the tree so that we can use `showDialog()`?

Comment: @LukePighetti Did you manage to do it without actually providing the key?

Comment: `showDialog(_navigator.currentContext)` should get you heading in the right direction

Comment: I am having a dropdown in the bottom bar. and the dropdown is throwing the error. how can I pass the navigator to the dropdown.

Answer (score -4):

Rename this context variable to something else

```
builder: (context, child)
```

You are getting name clashs for the context you are using here:

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/app'),
```

Comment: Doesn't matter in this case because I use the navigator inside the class (that I replaced here by the `FlatButton`). See edit